# Xamarin iOS layout changes after adding launch screen storyboard

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, autolayout

I inherited an old xamarin codebase. It launches in this strange windowed form with top and bottom black bars (pictured below). It also uses a launch image. As soon as I start using a launch storyboard, the app becomes fullscreen (no top/bottom black bars), and as a result, all the layout is messed up.

Does anyone know how to have the launch storyboard without removing the black bars?

[image: non fullscreen layout]

Comment: But why do you wanna keep the black bars? Those bars are there because that app is not using the safeAre, meaning those bars are not supposed to be there. My suggestion is: redo the splashscreen using the storyboard.

Answer (score 4):

Not really, this is a feature.

Apple says, "Your app will run in Full Screen Display Mode on iPhone X, iPhone XS, iPhone XS Max, and iPhone XR if your project’s base SDK is set to iOS 11 or later and you have a Launch Storyboard or iPhone X launch image."

So you adding the storyboard triggers the app to run in full screen mode.

ref: https://developer.apple.com/iphone/, search for "Enable full screen native resolution".

Comment: This is correct. You have a couple of options here if you want to keep the old ratio:
1) DO NOT use storyboards. 
2) If you MUST use storyboards, then you must use iOS SDK below version 11, like mentioned above. The SDKs come bundled into XCode. In order to have SDK 10.3, you will need XCode 9. Beware that newer macOS versions & Xamarin.iOS versions may now work with it.